# Jquery .animate acts unintentionaly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know why suddenly the sidebar moves unintentionally. I'm creating a fixed sidebar that show only when hovered.

When I slowly point the mouse on the parent div `#containter` element it works fine, but when I move the mouse several times on the parent div element `#containter` the div shows and hide like insane. And also there an area where the parent div shows even you didn't actually hovered on the parent div.

I'm using this code.

**HTML**

```
<div id="containter"><!-- parent div -->
  <div class="wrapdownload">
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapdownload">
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapdownload">
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#containter {
  width: 140px;
  height: 282px;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 30px;
  left: -104px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.wrapdownload {
  width: 100px;
  height: 90px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#containter").mouseenter(function(event) {
    $("#containter").animate({
      left: "1px"
    });
  });

  $("#containter").mouseleave(function(event) {
    $("#containter").animate({
      left: "-104px"
    });
  });
});
```

When you hover on the parent div for six times the div show 6 times also. I just want it to show when the mouse is pointed on div element and if i move the mouse outside the parent div, it must hide.

Here is the sample on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/py0622ms/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `stop()` method:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#containter").mouseenter(function(event) {
    $("#containter").stop().animate({
      left: "1px"
    });
  });

  $("#containter").mouseleave(function(event) {
    $("#containter").stop().animate({
      left: "-104px"
    });
  });
});
```

Working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/py0622ms/7/